# http_code => 0 при отправке на api webmaster yandex

Tags: php, wordpress, php-curl, яндекс-вебмастер

Используя документацию Яндекс API Вебмастер, я смог получить OAuth Token и список сайтов с `Host_ID`, а так же `user_id` от Яндекс.

Теперь хочу отправить в оригинальный текст через api

```
$text = 'some text';

$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$text = urlencode($text);
$text = "<Data><content>{$text}</content></Data>";
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/xml',
    'Authorization: OAuth '.$this-> getYandexToken(),
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($text)
);

// 1. инициализация
$ch = curl_init();

// 2. указываем параметры, включая url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.webmaster.yandex.net/v4/user/".$user_id['result'].
    "/hosts/".$this - > getWebsiteId().
    "/original-texts/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $text);
// 3. получаем HTML в качестве результата
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

В `$info` получаю ответ

```
Array ( [url] => https://api.webmaster.yandex.net/v4/user/{myId}/hosts/{hostId}/original-texts/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 20 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.020971 [namelookup_time] => 0.001156 [connect_time] => 0.008732 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 213.180.193.61 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 192.168.1.13 [local_port] => 57945 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 2 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => HTTPS [appconnect_time_us] => 0 [connect_time_us] => 8732 [namelookup_time_us] => 1156 [pretransfer_time_us] => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 [total_time_us] => 20971 )
```

В Оригинальные тексты ничего не добавляется.
Где я ошибаюсь при построении cURL запроса?

**UPD: Решение**

В `$headers` убираем все, оставляем только:

```
 $headers = array(
            'Content-type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization: OAuth ' . $this->getYandexToken()
        );
```

Comment: Используйте стандартные функции:

wp_remote, wp_remote_get, wp_remote_post

они вам сократят размер кода для запросов. Там будет проще посмотреть ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD: Решение**

В $headers убираем все, оставляем только:

```
 $headers = array(
            'Content-type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization: OAuth ' . $this->getYandexToken()
        );
```